# Can't modify files on Cpanel

Tags: cpanel

I got a problem with modifying files in cpanel, got error message said "Permission denied!" and I changed files permission to read, write and execute for user level, but still can make changes on these files. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You do not have access to change that file permission. I think your host has disable that file access, so please contact your hosting provider and ask them to update the correct permission and ownership of your files.

Answer (score 0):

You will indeed need to contact your hosting provider as this can also be the result of incorrect file ownership.

If the issue is with a specific file and works for the rest, they might have as well locked the file on purpose.